# Fastest and reliable way to check if an image url is broken

Tags: facebook, image, validation, url, request

Do you guys know a "fast and reliable way" to check if an image url is broken? Currently I'm doing a head request to the url and check if the status code is 200, but it is really really slow especially if I'm checking many image urls. Maybe you guys know a better solution?

What we're doing is replicating facebook's url preview when you paste a url in the status form and allow the user to choose an image that will go with their post. The problem is it also includes broken image urls so I need to exclude them.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Facebook are caching the results from the URLs.

Second, not all servers support HEAD requests, so if you HEAD request fails you should also try with GET. You can optimize it to check only if the fail is different from 404, normally it should be 405 Method Not Allowed or 501 Not Implemented.

And third have in mind that checking the URL directly makes you vulnerable to DoS attacks. It is enough someone to post a link to page that just keeps the connection open for a long time several times and you will get blocked by multiple unused connections.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

http://embedly.github.io/jquery-preview/demo/

...works similar to Facebook's URL post preview.

Cheers!